# Time dilation: Whose clock will be slow on comparison?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

Let us take an inertial frame $S^\prime$ moving w.r.t another inertial frame $S$ with a uniform velocity ${\vec V}=V\hat{x}$. Let us imagine the following situation. Let the $S$-observer and the $S^\prime$-observer be equipped with identical clocks. Let us also assume that to start with the frames coincided and when they did, we ensured that their clocks were synchronized i.e. $t=t'=20:00$.

Now suppose the $S^\prime$-frame crosses the S frame (event 1) at $t=20:00$ and crosses another point (event 2) at time $t=20:05$, as measured by the $S$-observer. After this, the $S$ observer makes a telephone call to the $S^\prime$-observer to ask what is the time recorded by the $S'$-observer's clock. Will it also read 20:05?

If $S'$-obserser says that his clock reads $20:03$, then definitely $S'-$clock has become slow w.r.t the $S$-clock. But this would violate the principle of relativity. The principle of relativity says that the $S^\prime$-observer should also find that $S$-observer's clock runs slow. I am confused.

Comment: S' frame is no longer inertial since it stopped its motion after finite interval of time(I.e. velocity changed ). The Lorentz transformation rule applies for inertial frames only

Comment: @KP99 But your time cannot change in a sudden just because you accelerated! Can you get this? It is not possible that your clock readed 10:50am and it suddenly changed to 1:00 am just because you accelerated at the end

Comment: Sorry OP i also have the same confusion but it is not easy to make people understand what you need because they already have some information and they don't want it to be called as useless

Comment: @Predaking Askboss the frame was initially moving at constant velocity but it stopped motion abruptly, which involves arbitrarily large deceleration. So the time dilation effect will be very significant. In reality, this scenario is unrealistic, you can't suddenly stop your motion, so the clock reading won't change suddenly

Comment: See section 7.2.3 of Tong's lecture note on special relativity( http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/relativity.html)

Comment: @Solidification you cannot both say that a frame is inertial and that it starts and stops. An inertial frame moves always with uniform velocity by definition. So do you want inertial frames or do you want frames that start and stop? Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: Frustrating conversation

Comment: @KP99 so remove that instant term and stop slowly taking 10 to 20 sec or more. Is it okay for you

Comment: @Dale edited to make the frames inertial

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the $S'$ frame crosses the $S$ frame"?

Comment: "Let us also assume that to start with the frames coincided".  Two frames either coincide or they don't.

Answer (score 2):

You should not interpret time dilation as meaning that moving clocks slow down. Instead, imagine that all clocks, regardless of their relative state of motion, tick at the same rate.

The consequence of relative motion is not that clocks slow down, but that clocks become out of synchronisation- the effect is known as the relativity of simultaneity.

If we take the example you gave, the observer S' meets S when each of their clocks reads 20:00. Three minutes later, according to S', S' meets another clock in the frame of S that reads 12:05. At the same instant, according to S, the clock held by S reads 12:05 too, while the clock of S' reads only 12:03 and so appears to be time dilated. However, in the frame of S', at the moment when the second meeting of clocks happens, the clock held by S registers only 20:01:48 while the local time in the frame of S' is 20:03, so the clock held by S seems to be time dilated from the perspective of S'.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that the S' observer uses clock C, while the S observer uses two synchronized clocks A and B. Clock C is initially co-located at the position of clock A at time $t=t′=20:00$, after which C moves towards B at which it arrives at $t=20:05$ from the viewpoint of S. Since C is time dilated from the viewpoint of S, it will lag behind and only indicate $t'=20:03$. Now, the relativity principle tells us that from the viewpoint of S', clock B should be time dilated. How is this possible, when we already know that C $(t'=20:03)$ lags behind B $(t=20:05)$?

The answer is simple: The above example rests on the assumption, that A and B are synchronous in S. However from the viewpoint of S', A and B are both in motion and are *not* synchronous due to [relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity). So when A and C both indicate $t=t'=20:00$, clock B is ticking ahead of them and is already indicating $t=20:03$. Now, clock B is moving toward clock C and ticks at a *time dilated rate*. So when B arrives at C the following is the case: The time dilated clock B will progress only by 2 minutes so that it finally indicates

$$t=20:03+00:02=20:05$$

while the "faster ticking" clock C progresses 3 minutes to finally indicate

$$t'=20:00+00:03=20:03$$

As we can see, despite the fact that clock B is time dilated in S' and therefore is ticking at a slower rate than C, it is nevertheless more advanced than clock C when they meet. So both S and S' see each other time dilated in accordance with the relativity principle, they both get the same result, and there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to suppose frames S and S' as very long trains with one synchronized clock in each wagon. That means: all clocks are synchronized in S, and all clocks are syncronized in S'. (But according remarked by other answers, clocks of S are not synchronized with S'). S' has a velocity $v$ for the frame S.

The Lorentz transformation for time (for c = 1) is:
$\Delta t' = \gamma(\Delta t - v\Delta x)$

After $\Delta t = 5$ minutes, the wagon of S' that met the wagon of reference of S at $20:00$ will be displaced by $\Delta x$

$\Delta x = v\Delta t$ in the frame S. So $$\Delta t' = \gamma(\Delta t - v^2\Delta t) = \gamma (1 - v^2)\Delta t = \frac{\Delta t}{\gamma}$$

So, this wagon of S' will see its clock showing a smaller time than what is displayed in the wagon of S that is momentarily in front. As all clocks of S are synchronized, it is equivalent to a radio call to S.

The same is valid the other way around. S has a velocity -v  for the frame S':

$\Delta t = \gamma(\Delta t' + v\Delta x')$

After $\Delta t'$ minutes, the wagon of S that met the wagon of reference of S' at $20:00$ will be displaced by $\Delta x'$

$\Delta x' = -v\Delta t'$ in the frame S' $$\Delta t = \gamma(\Delta t' - v^2\Delta t') = \gamma(1 - v^2)\Delta t') = \frac{\Delta t'}{\gamma}$$

So, the same is valid for S' and S. If we take the time calculated before by S', and substitute $$\Delta t' = \frac{5}{\gamma} \implies \Delta t = \frac{5}{\gamma^2}$$

What allows the symmetry is to compare wagons momentarily in front of others to have instantaneous information about differences of time. That way, it is not the same pair of wagons compared in each situation.